# Value of 'scope' to use when getting OAuth token to read Outlook email

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, outlook, webjob

I have an existing application (a console app that runs as a WebJob) that uses Exchange Web Services to read emails in a shared Outlook 365 mailbox. This works, but it's using basic authentication and I want to use OAuth instead. I'm attempting to do this using Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder to get an access token. I've read various articles and posts online which seem to give conflicting advice about what the 'scope' parameter should be when calling AcquireTokenForClient. Some say https://graph.microsoft.com/.default, others say https://outlook.office.com/.default or https://outlook.office365.com/.default. Others seem to suggest that it should be Mail.Read rather than .Default. I've tried all of the above without success. Can anyone tell me what the correct value for 'scope' is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have registered your app for an Office 365 tenant. We are using EWS with modern authentication successfully for some time now. To access the users' mailboxes in your tenant using OAuth authentication you have to grant the registered application the API permission Exchange - full_access_as_app and use https://outlook.office.com/.default as scope.

```
var clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create("applicationId")
    .WithTenantId("tenantId")
    .WithClientSecret("secret")
    .Build();

var authenticationResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://outlook.office.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
var accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

Then add the token to the authorization header of the EWS requests.

Comment: Hi Kay, thanks for your answer. To be honest, that was 13 months ago, and I no longer remember the details, but to the best of my memory I believe the solution was along the lines you suggest, so I'm going to accept this as the answer.